# Different results when encrypting with Bouncy Castle and Node.js

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, cryptography

I'm trying to perform the same encryption operation in Java (using Bouncy Castle) and Node.js, however I receive different results in each language. Below are my attempted implementations - can anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

### Java Code

```java
//Java code:
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.DESedeEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.*;
//...
String inputString = "24778721";  //8 bytes
String keyString = "lf9aodkflaen7;ad";
BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(new DESedeEngine());
byte[] key = keyString.getBytes();
byte[] input = inputString.getBytes();
cipher.init(isEncode, new KeyParameter(key));       

byte[] result = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];       
int outputLen = cipher.processBytes(input, 0, input.length, result, 0);
cipher.doFinal(result, outputLen);

//result is "65dcbb2e08e6d66e"
```

### JavaScript Code

```
//node.js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var key = "lf9aodkflaen7;ad";
var data = "24778721";
var keybuf = new Buffer(key);
var databuf = new Buffer(data);

var cipher = crypto.createCipher('des-ede', keybuf);
cipher.update(databuf);
var result = cipher.final();

// result is "bf d2 cc 51 c5 e9 ef 38"
```

Alternative using `createCipheriv` function:

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede', keybuf.toString("binary"), '');
cipher.update(databuf);
var result = cipher.final();

// result is  "7a 24 bf 56 04 18 e3 6a"
```

Comment: The first step in such problems is to ensure you are using the same algorithm mode and padding in both environments. It seems like you are making use of the default choices from Bouncy Castle and Node.js. Find out what those defaults are.

Comment: In the sources of bouncycastle, 1)"new BufferedBlockCipher(new DESedeEngine())" has no padding processing 2) block_size in DESedeEngine is 8 bytes

Comment: Yes, but node has default PKCS#7 padding. Using the double argument `createCipher` method obviously won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there with the second try. This code will give you the same value like with Bouncy Castle:

```
//node.js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var key = "lf9aodkflaen7;ad";
var data = "24778721";
var keybuf = new Buffer(key);
var databuf = new Buffer(data);

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede', keybuf, '');
var crypted = cipher.update(databuf, 'utf8', 'hex');

console.log(crypted);
//65dcbb2e08e6d66e
```